# Postgres build comment threads using BFS, for a set of N root comments - Trouble writing SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

#### Context

I have a comments trees that look something like this stored in my PostgreSQL database. Each comment is denoted by a letter (*A, B, etc.*). They are all "associated together in a thread" because they each contain a column *ancestors* which is labelled in blue below, which contains pointers to the IDs to all the comments above it.

This is just 1 "thread" but there can be many of these structures, and they can be nested till N depth. Each comment also has a field *children_count* which indicates how many children it has directly below it. Moreover, they have a *score* column which indicates how many upvotes they've received from users.

[image]

#### My goal

I want to be able to have these sentences translated into SQL:

*For N root comments ordered by score, I'd like for each to do a BFS on the children of that root comment, each time when given the option to jump to the next level down, picking the post with the highest score field. For each "children-thread-traversal" I'd also like to cap how many M results are returned max from each thread.*

*In total, my return would be N root comments, each with at-most M children, at every step sorted by score. Where each comment is obviously "attached" to the root via a branch, AKA, if C replies to B which replies to A, I don't want to return A and C, but not B which connects them.*

#### My attempt, schema, and example comment

This currently returns everything I (think I) want for each individual comment thread, but I can't get it to execute this for the N root comments so that I don't have to loop over this query a bunch of times and manually input the ID of a new root comment to find.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE comment_hierarchy AS (
  SELECT c.id, c.score, c.content, ARRAY[c.id] AS path, 1 AS level, c.id AS root_id, 1 AS discovery_order, c.ancestors
  FROM comments c
  WHERE COALESCE(ancestors, '{}') = '{}'
    AND post_id = 1 -- [input] post id
    AND c.id = 40 -- Specify the root comment ID here

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c.id, c.score, c.content, ch.path || c.id, ch.level + 1, CASE WHEN ch.root_id = c.id THEN c.id ELSE ch.root_id END, ch.discovery_order + 1, c.ancestors
  FROM comments c
  INNER JOIN comment_hierarchy ch ON ch.id = ANY(c.ancestors) OR (ch.id = ch.root_id AND ch.root_id != c.id)
  WHERE ch.level < 5 -- Maximum recursion depth of 5? Needed?
    AND c.score < ch.score
    AND c.ancestors[1] = 40 -- Filter by ancestors[1] = 40
), ranked_comments AS (
  SELECT id, score, content, discovery_order, ancestors, root_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY root_id ORDER BY cardinality(ancestors), score DESC, discovery_order) AS row_num
  FROM comment_hierarchy
)
SELECT id, score, content, discovery_order, ancestors
FROM ranked_comments
WHERE row_num <= 100
ORDER BY root_id, row_num;
```

My schema for comments looks something like this:

`id`, `user_id`, `post_id`, `content`, `score`, `children_count`, `ancestors`

Example comment: `1, anc89au4w3unowaa, 532, "foobar", 42, 4, {33, 45, 93}`

In my example above my `ancestors` comprised of letters for simplicity, but really it's the IDs of other comments.

#### Ending

How can I design this?

Comment: you have 7 column but 8 values. why not reconstuct the image as data  odeally in a dbfiddle

Comment: @nbk sorry, what do you mean? all I can think of is the example I gave which has 7 columns in the legend, and 7 examples columns. maybe I'm thinking of the wrong thing?